# My d3 js chart brushed and zoomed is not working for background

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My d3 js chart brushed and zoomed is not working for background.

Inside my `brushed` function I have below code, while brushing and zooming it should reflect the orange background.

```
var orangeBack = svg
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", margin.left)
  // .attr("x", function (d) {
  //   return xScale(1568283720049);
  // })
  .attr("y", margin.top)
  .attr("height", containerHeight - 120)
  // .attr("width",  200)
  .attr("width", function (d) {
    return xScale(1568283720049) - xScale(1567851720049) + 10;
  })
  .style("stroke", bordercolor)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("opacity", 0.05)
  .style("stroke-width", border);
```

currently I have given the timestamp directly e.g. `xScale(1568283720049)` this can be calculated based on new scale dynamically.

code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bhabha-4ullr?file=/src/TimelineChart.js

[image]

after brushing and zooming -

[image]

Comment: @TreffnonX Yes, I want to give the width automatically in case of brused and zoomed.